# How to solve "no public key" error with dget?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I'm trying to download some package binaries using `dget` but I keep getting a "No public key" error.

```
dget  http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gl-image-display/gl-image-display_0.10-2.dsc
```

Returns the output

```
dget: retrieving http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gl-image-display/gl-image-display_0.10-2.dsc
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2243  100  2243    0     0   9080      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  9080
dget: using existing gl-image-display_0.10.orig.tar.gz
dget: using existing gl-image-display_0.10-2.debian.tar.xz
dscverify: gl-image-display_0.10-2.dsc failed signature check:
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
gpg: Signature made Wed 06 Apr 2022 04:57:07 PM MDT
gpg:                using RSA key B5E2FA190FDF9AFE218889CFACC7C2CF30941188
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
Validation FAILED!!
```

I tried to use the configuration variable `DGET_VERIFY=no` to disable checking signatures of downloaded source packages. (See [Documenation](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/devscripts/dget.1.en.html)), but I still get the same error.

How can I either fix this error or disable the validation check?

Comment: @SottoVoce Yes, that works. Thank you. Do you want to convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The man page indicates `dget -u` will disable verification.  I haven't used `dget` before, so I don't know if this command-line option has the same effects as the config variable, but it's worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Download the public key from Debian's key-server so you can verify against it:

```
$ gpg --keyserver keyring.debian.org \
>     --recv-keys B5E2FA190FDF9AFE218889CFACC7C2CF30941188
gpg: key ED63B6125A1D1561: public key imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

Then you can `dget` that package:

```
$ dget  http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gl-image-display/gl-image-display_0.10-2.dsc
dget: retrieving http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gl-image-display/gl-image-display_0.10-2.dsc
dget: retrieving http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gl-image-display/gl-image-display_0.10.orig.tar.gz
dget: retrieving http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gl-image-display/gl-image-display_0.10-2.debian.tar.xz
gl-image-display_0.10-2.dsc:
      Good signature found
   validating gl-image-display_0.10.orig.tar.gz
   validating gl-image-display_0.10-2.debian.tar.xz
All files validated successfully.
dpkg-source: info: extracting gl-image-display in gl-image-display-0.10
dpkg-source: info: unpacking gl-image-display_0.10.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: unpacking gl-image-display_0.10-2.debian.tar.xz
```